# Generating array of word pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a problem where I have to read a text file made of 264064 words into a buffer and then create an array of word-pointers in a separate array. I am not sure how to go about creating the array of word-pointers which points to different amount of characters in the buffer. Any hints on how to approach this problem?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,wordCount=0;
    long bufsize;
    char ch;

    //Open File and get number of lines in file
    FILE *fp = fopen("words2.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    do {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            wordCount++;
        }

    } while (ch != EOF);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%d\n",wordCount);

    //Reading Words into buffer rawtext
    char *rawtext;
    fp = fopen("words2.txt", "rb");

    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0) {
            bufsize = ftell(fp);
            if (bufsize == -1) {
                exit(1);
            }
            rawtext = malloc(sizeof(char) * (bufsize + 1));

            if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0) { exit(1); }

            size_t newLen = fread(rawtext, sizeof(char), bufsize, fp);
            if (ferror(fp) != 0) {
                fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
            } else {
                rawtext[newLen++] = '\0';
            }
        }
        //Print out buffer
        printf("%s",rawtext);
        fclose(fp);
        free(rawtext);//Free allocated memory

        char *ptr[wordCount];//Array for word-pointers
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you opening the same file twice?

Comment: To create an array of pointers you do this: `char *word_array[MAX_WORDS];`

Comment: I kept getting an error after reading the number of lines and for some reason it worked after closing and opening the file again.

Comment: Is there one word per line? Because in that case, there is no reason to first read all data (characters) into memory first. You can just read things line by line in one go.

Comment: @kaylum what if MAX_WORDS is not know at compile time, or (for v-len arrays) the array wouldn't fit into the stack? You may want to need a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: One way to do is simply to allocate the required space for each individual word, and store the pointers to those allocations/words in another array. Overall though, your question as it currently is, is a bit too open for a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your `rawtext` (i.e. do not free it), you could use `strchr('\n')` to go through the content, store to the array the current position, detect every new line char, terminate the string at this new line character, and go ahead. Thereby, your `ptr`-array will point to each word inside `rawtext` at the end (that's why you should not free `rawtext` then, because the pointers would then point to invalid memory):

The following code should work:

```
char* currWord = rawtext;
int nrOfWords = 0;
char* newlinePos;
while ((newlinePos = strchr(currWord,'\n')) != NULL) {
  *newlinePos = '\0';
  ptr[nrOfWords++] = currWord;
  currWord = newlinePos + 1;
}
if (*currWord) {
  ptr[nrOfWords++] = currWord;
}
```

Side note: expression `char *ptr[wordCount]` might put your pointer array on the stack, which has limited space, at least less than the heap. This could get a problem if your file contains a lot of words. Use `char *ptr = malloc((wordCount+1) * sizeof(char*))` to reserve memory on the heap. Note also the `+1` after wordCount for the case that the last word is not terminated by a new line.